# not able to correctly detect double quotes in java

Tags: java

I am trying to use string split to solve my problem, but my program is only partially right. I am new to regex and still trying to understand how to implement it for complicated patterns.

I have below mentioned string formats:

```
String a = Internal module control "memory" sensor
String b = Internal module control memory "sensor"
String c = "Internal" module control "memory" sensor
```

The output I expect should be like:

```
String a = Internal module control "memory"/memory //(with or without quotes is fine) 
String b = Internal module control memory "sensor"/sensor //(both are fine)
String c = "Internal"/Internal module control "memory"/memory //(here also both are fine)
```

**What I tried:**

My program works perfectly fine for `String a` and `String c`, but when I come across case like mentioned in `String b` it fails.

```
String[] words = a.split("\"");
for (int i=0; i<words.length-1; i++) {
             final_desc += words[i];
        }
```

my o/p for `a`, `b` and `c` is:

```
a = Internal module control memory 

(fails) I expect: b = Internal module control memory sensor // I get b = Internal module control memory

c = Internal module control memory
```

**P.S.**

In general, I want to remove everything after last quote no matter how many quotes there are in the given string and if there are quotes in the last word then it should consider that word also, like presented in `String b`

Comment: Your output is missing the last word. Try to replace ``i<words.length-1`` with ``i<words.length``.

Comment: In that case I will get `String a` and `String c` wrong, while getting only `String b` as correct.

Comment: What constitutes a correct output in general? Removing quotes and everything after the last quote?

Comment: @4castle yes if quotes are not removed then also its fine. But removing everything after last quote is mandatory. as shown above in output

Comment: `a.replaceAll("\"[^\"]*$", "\"")` removes everything after the last quote.

Comment: Okay so when I use your code on `String c` I get output like `Internal "` but it should be `Internal module control memory`. I also added P.S in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the other version of `split` which takes an additional `limit` argument.

So

**replace**

`String[] words = b.split("\"");`

**with**

`String[] words = b.split("\"", -1);`

**reason**

Here specifying a negative limit value will make `split` apply the pattern as many times as possible and also not disregard the trailing empty strings. Read the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) for more information.

Comment: This works perfectly. And its easy to fit into my current program.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `replace()` method of the String.

[Replace method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replace.htm)

Remove this block

```
String[] words = a.split("\"");
for (int i=0; i<words.length-1; i++) {
             final_desc += words[i];
        }
```

and put on its place this code

```
int lastQuote = a.lastIndexOf("\"");

if(lastQuote > 0) {
   final_desc = a.subString(0, lastQuote).replace("\"", "");
}else {
   final_desc = a;
}
```

Comment: If i am not wrong, this will only replace quotes with no quotes. however, it must also remove the word after last quote. like e.g. that is shown in the question.

Comment: thank you for this. I get what you are doing. I accepted the other answer because it summed up everything what I wanted in just one line. Its also using split which I am already using in the code.